# Is there a word for "one who summons"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a noun to describe a person or entity that summons? "summoner"/"summonist"?

(I am trying to name a software application. Other apps that cooperate with it are already named "Archivist" and "Flashback", and the group of three apps will be named DejaVu. The app in question allows the user to define a "neighborhood of precedents" for Flashback to retrieve from the archives maintained by Archivist.)

Comment: Tell us what happened when you looked for your two candidate words in some dictionaries.

Comment: @GEdgar Hmm, MSWord highlighted both as spelling errors so I assumed they didn't exist. I'd still be interested in any synonymns though, because of the connotations of summoner.

Comment: @Museful [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/summon?q=summoner#summon__16). If you want synonyms, please show your research with a thesaurus, so that others don't waste time repeating what you have already found. ELU is a not a general research tool.

Comment: My dictionary shows "summoner".  But not "summonist".  The moral, I guess, is: use a real dictionary, not MS Word, as your reference.

Comment: A sherrif, in many counties in these here United States. Don

Comment: I'd go for summonist. Joking ;)

Comment: What on Earth is a "neighbourhood of precedents"?

Comment: As for suggestions: possibly "procurer", "fetcher", "governor" (for governing the other apps), or "gateway" (referring to the app's function as a gateway between Archivist and Flashback).

Comment: @COTO A *procurer* is somebody who obtains things; a *fetcher* is somebody who goes and gets things; a *governor* is someone or something that controls things; a *gateway* is an opening in a wall. None of those words is appropriate to the request in the question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: As I understand it, the purpose of this third app is to facilitate the retrieval of information out of "Archivist" for display in "Flashback". Either the app performs the retrieval itself, in which case "procurer" and "fetcher" seem appropriate, or the app simply solicits and mediates the exchange of data between the subordinate apps, in which case "governor" and "gateway" seem appropriate. The verbs "summon" and "conjure" have a lot of baggage associated with them, and the same is true of the noun "summoner". Perhaps "solicitor" due to its role soliciting records?

Comment: @COTO Flashback does the fetching/searching. This third app is a front-end that interacts with the user and then tells Flashback what kinds of things to search for in the archives. It is like a graphical language in which the user specifies what kinds/neighborhood of incidents from the archives she is interested in. The family of apps is called DejaVu because these incidents are graphically overlayed over a "current incident" and in some sense resemble it like plots that are similar i.e. are from a "neighborhood" around it.

Comment: @COTO I originally thought something similar to "Summoner" may go well with "Archivist" but it is true that "Summoner" has perhaps a bit too much baggage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obvious word would be ***summoner*** . But be careful. Though no such named office exists in the British judicial system, the name used to be that of an officer in English medieval ecclesiastical courts.

Indeed one of Chaucer's pilgrims was a Summoner. A modern prose rendering of the Prologue notes the office of the Summoner as:

> An officer or constable whose task was to summon delinquents to appear
>   before ecclesiastical courts, enforce payment of tithes and church
>   dues etc. He also had power to punish adultery, fornication, and other
>   sins not punishable by common law. The *Friar's Tale* is a satire on
>   the abuses practised by Summoners.

Chaucer describes his Summoner in the Prologue as having:

> ...slit eyes and a flaming red visage like a cherub's, all covered with
>   pimples. He was as randy and lecherous as a sparrow. Children were
>   afraid of his face with its scabbed black eyebrows and scraggy beard.
>   No mercury, white lead, sulphur, borax, ceruse, cream of tartar, or
>   other ointments that cleanse and burn could rid him of his white
>   pustules or the pimply knobs on his cheeks. He had a great love of
>   garlic, onions, and leeks, and of drinking strong wine red as blood,
>   which made him roar and gabble like a madman. When really drunk on
>   wine he's speak nothing but Latin...He was a tolerant, easy-going dog,
>   as good a fellow as you might hope to find. For a quart of wine he'd
>   allow any rascal of a priest to keep his concubine for a twelvemonth
>   and excuse him altogether; however he was well able to fleece a
>   greenhorn on the sly...

David Wright: Modern prose rendering of *Canterbury Tales by Geoffrey Chaucer*.

Answer (score 4):

You can try some variation of the word: **conjuring**, but I do not know how appropriate it will be for an app name.

> **Conjuror** - Person(magician, medium) performing summoning of ghosts etc.

Answer (score 3):

"The Summoner's Tale" is one of Chaucer's Canterbury Tales.  It seems there is a video game, "Summoner".

Answer (score 1):

For a software application, **"commander"** comes to mind.

> - commander (noun) a person who commands, especially a commanding officer. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/commander)

a **"convener"** might also fit.

> - convener (noun) a person who convenes or chairs a meeting, committee, etc. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/convener)